# Spring boot after https: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start.

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I followed a guide to enable https in Spring Boot. The application was beforehand working on https://localhost:8080

I've created a `keystore.jks` which is in the same directory as my `application.properties`, which now looks like:

```
# Define a custom port instead of the default 8080
server.port = 8444
# Tell Spring Security (if used) to require requests over HTTPS
security.require-ssl=true
# The format used for the keystore
server.ssl.key-store-type:PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=<somepassword>
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

Now, if I run the main method to start the spring boot app, it throws:

```
Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8444, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

The port isn't in use, so it must be misconfiguration?

I'm unsure of what to change. It's a simple SPA app, Spring just serves an index.html and has a single REST endpoint. How should tomcat/spring be configured to accept https in this case, and start up without errors?

Comment: small type at `server.ssl.key-store-type` line. `yml` uses `:` . `{file}.properties` uses `=`

Comment: plus try to run with debug flag. It can help to find some hidden errors

Comment: I'm too having the same problem. Have you found a solution

Comment: Yes. The pathing is for the ROOT of the project, not relative in the folder. So In application properties, the path for the key should be `server.ssl.key-store=backend/src/main/resources/keystore.p12`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I too had the same problem and was able to fix it. My problem was generating the `keystore.p12` file.

If you have a certificate file and private key file, you can generate`keystore.p12` file using following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <mycert.crt> -inkey <mykey.key> -out keystore.p12 -name <alias>
```

You will be prompted for a password,there you can enter a password you like.
Once the keystore file is generated copy it to the directory where your `.jar` file exist.

Following is a working example configuration.

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=file:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-alias=<alias>
```

Note the key store file path `file:keystore.p12` if it is going to reside in the same directory as the executable `.jar` file.

Comment: Also the same problem - wrong cert file.

1) A tip for validate the file. If you are on Windows, double click the *.p12 file, Windows will start the 'Certificate Import Wizard'.

2) one more thing, key-alias is not required

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same issue by using the following configuration

```
# Define a custom port instead of the default 8080
server.port=8443
# Tell Spring Security (if used) to require requests over HTTPS
security.require-ssl=true
# The format used for the keystore 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=root0
```

I removed alias name and it worked perfectly. 
"You probably won't need a key alias, since there will only be one key entry" referred from 
[TOMCAT SSL Error: Alias name does not identify a key entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799660/tomcat-ssl-error-alias-name-does-not-identify-a-key-entry?rq=1)

Comment: Yes by removing or commenting server.ssl.key-alias=myalias from application.properties it works.

Comment: Word of advice: don't include passwords in your example :)

Comment: That is just a dummy password ;)

Answer (score 3):

From Spring Boot 2.0 and higher, you can ignore this property.

```
security.require-ssl=true
```

To enable SSL, use the below configuration in your application.properties

## The format used for the keystore

server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS

## The path to the keystore containing the certificate

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:somecert.jks

## The password used to generate the certificate

server.ssl.key-store-password=password

## The alias mapped to the certificate

server.ssl.key-alias=alias_name

> Note : server.ssl.key-store refers to the keystore location. Use
>   classpath prefix, if it is present in src/main/resources. Otherwise use,
>   file:/some/location.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as well but in my case the file path (in application.properties) for keystore file was incorrect on Linux and causing this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. for me **server.ssl.key-alias** was set to a wrong key. So, it sounds that some **server** mis-configurations in **application.properties** can cause this error message to appear.