# How to make my Spring Boot microservice run using HTTPS?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https, configuration

I have a microservice implemented with Spring Boot (originally started with 2.0.6 now 2.1.8) and it runs well using port 8080. 
Now I have to switch to TLS to let the (REST) service work as a webhook using HTTPS but I always get

```
2020-01-02 17:14:38.929 DEBUG [-,,,] 19072 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:220)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
    at de.mediciliving.cloud.crm.CrmServiceApplication.main(CrmServiceApplication.java:21)

2020-01-02 17:14:38.930 ERROR [-,,,] 19072 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8444, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I followed [HTTPS using Self-Signed Certificate in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate#generating-keystore) to create the keystore using:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias MyAlias -keystore keystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -storepass xxxxxx -validity 730 -keysize 2048
```

In my `application.properties` I defined this:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.port=${APPLICATION_PORT:8443}
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=xxxxxx
#server.ssl.key-password=xxxxxx
# The format used for the keystore.
#server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
#server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12

server.ssl.key-alias=MyAlias
```

I have no other service running listening on that port and I even restarted IntelliJ to ensure that there is no running/listening service.

I have searched the web for some days now and I still couldn't get my service running using HTTPS. The error message is telling me nothing helpful. Since there is no other running service it must be the configuration but I don't know what exactly could cause this error.

In the POM I have:

```
<spring.boot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<tomcat.version>9.0.27</tomcat.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

...I found something to exclude binary resource files from filtering, so I considered it in the POM as well...
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/resources/**/*.p12</exclude>
</excludes>
```

I tried several ports like 443, 8443, 8082, ... and also using different certificate formats (PKCS12 and JKS) with no success.

When I do `keytool.exe -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass xxxxxx -list -storetype pkcs12`

I get:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

MyAlias, 02.01.2020, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 50:F3:52:68:4D:13:D9:C7:72:8E:9F:E9:60:40:DB:88:4D:1F:E8:75:2B:0A:08:C5:E2:F5:FA:D0:D7:0B:73:EB
```

Maybe it's helpful for you that I have this configuration in my service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends /*WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*/ ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] WHITELIST = {
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/error*",
            "/health"
    };

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(WHITELIST).permitAll();
//        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        // disables Cross-Site Request Forgery protection and CORS protection
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535131/spring-boot-after-https-the-tomcat-connector-configured-to-listen-on-port-8444?rq=1

Comment: I found this site already but none of the suggestions succeeded.

Comment: But it says: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured. So there must be something running on that port

Comment: It says as well: ...or the connector may be misconfigured! 
As I told you, I even restarted the IDE and there is no service running on my localhost listening to this port.

Answer (score 0):

```
Considering that you have added the JKS to your Java cacerts in your system.Below are the steps using JKS for enabling https. 

Step 1 : (Changes to application.properties)
server.port: 443
server.ssl.key-store: jks_file_path
server.ssl.key-store-password: ********
server.ssl.keyStoreType: JKS


Step 2 : Go to your run /debug configuration and use below in VM options.

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= cacert_file_path
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev (optional if you have profiling enabled)

    enter code here

Step 3 : Start application. 

Hope it will work.
```

Comment: I am new to this topic...do I have to define a trustStore manually, too? I edited my question to show ou how I generated the certificate. When I put your suggestions in the run configuration the start still fails.

Comment: No you don't have to define trustStore, it will already be there in your system. Lets consider java is installed on your C drive, then cacert will be available in below path.
path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security

So, you have add the generated certificate to your cacert file , you can do it using below command. Lets say your certificate name is localhost.cer , then command will be.

keytool -import -trustcacerts -file localhost.cer -alias localhost -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security"