# How to import a trusted SSL certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, keytool

I have a trusted `SSL` certificate `(Sectigo)` and would like to import it into a keystore in order to it to enable `HTTPS`.

This is the command that I was using to create a new keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file ssl/<XXX>.com.crt -keystore keystore1.p12 -storepass password
```

I have copied the keystore1.p12 file to my spring boot app under resources.

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore1.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

While running the app I am getting the following error:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
```

I have tried several answers via StackOverflow, unfortunately, I cant understand what is missing?

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the certificate a signed certificate of your server's private key or is it a third party CA certificate you need to trust to be able to talk to their service?

Comment: You imported a certificate. You didn't import the private key that belongs to it.

Comment: user207421 can you please elaborate on this. Can you add some example please ?

Comment: Well, how did you generate the certificate? You must have started with a keypair somewhere. Where? Normally you would (1) create the keypair in a keystore, (2) generate a CSR, (3) get it signed, and (4) import it back into the same keystore with the same alias as the initial keypair.

Comment: Duplicate of [TOMCAT SSL Error: Alias name does not identify a key entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799660/tomcat-ssl-error-alias-name-does-not-identify-a-key-entry?rq=1).

Comment: I didn't create the certificate originally. I got this inheritance when I joined the project. These are the files that I currently have: XXX.crt, XXX.csr, XXX.key (private key), and XXX.pem. Please correct me if I am wrong but what I understand from your last comment is that I need to start a new process since I don’t have the original keystore?

Comment: Have a look at the Aoache Tomcat SSL documentation and the `keytool` documentation. Probaby best to use the `openssl` command to turn your key and pem files into a .p12 and use that as the keystore, then import the signed certificate into that, again using the same alias.

Comment: Thank you user207421