# How to configure existing SSL .cer to Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

**I have configured this certificate with nginx on production and working fine. But I want to configure it in spring boot application itself.**

1. I have generated CSR from some machine to get the certificate
2. SSL provider sent me a .cer certificate

Using below command converted .cer to .p12

```
keytool -import -alias springboot -file <mydomain>.crt -keystore <mydomain>.p12 -storepass <somepassword>
```

Configured Spring Boot properties as below

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:<mydomain>.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<somepassword>
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot
```

But spring boot application is failing to start with below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [springboot] does not identify a key entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-storetype pkcs12` to the keytool command.

According to [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799660/tomcat-ssl-error-alias-name-does-not-identify-a-key-entry). It was caused by the Embedded tomcat was not able to identity the private key and public key separately. pkcs12 type should solve that because because it bundles the private key too.

Even though you use the PKCS12 format, in your keytool command you didn't specified the storetype. Therefore try using below command.

```
keytool -import -alias springboot -file <mydomain>.crt -keystore <mydomain>.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass <somepassword>
```

Or

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -keystore <mydomain>.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -alias springboot -file <mydomain>.crt
```

Alternatively You can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#) to make it a p12 file also.

Comment: In Java 9 up `keytool` defaults to PKCS12 and specifying it accomplishes nothing. Yes any SSL/TLS/HTTPS server requires 'bundling' privatekey and cert(s), which BOTH JKS and PKCS12 can do, but NEITHER with `keytool -import[cert]`; _that_ was the problem in the Q you link, and applies to your first two attempts also. OTOH `openssl pkcs12 -export` CAN create PKCS12 with privatekey and cert IF you have the privatekey to give to it; OP didn't say so, but if they had access to a working nginx config that must have included the privatekey in a form OpenSSL can handle.