# Importing existing certificate to Tomcat server

Tags: certificate, tomcat9

I have a existing certificate (abc.crt) on Jboss server. This certificate is used in existing application to authenticate users from other system. Now I am working on migrating this application from Jboss to Tomcat 9.

Based on some online information, I have come to know to follow below steps to import the certificate in tomcat

1. Create keystore

keytool -importcert -file abc.crt -keystore xyz.jks -alias=pingfedcert

2. Modify server.xml and add connector

> ```
> <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>                connectionTimeout="20000"
>                redirectPort="443" />
>
> <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
>            maxThreads="150"
>            SSLEnabled="true"
>            scheme="https"
>            secure="true"
>            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
>            keystoreFile="conf/xyz.jks"
>            keystorePass="pingfed12" 
>          keyAlias="pingfedcert" />
> ```

3. Tomcat server restart and I get below error on server restart

   **org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]**
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1049)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1042)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
   **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [pingfedcert] does not identify a key entry**
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1240)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1046)
   ... 13 more
   **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [pingfedcert] does not identify a key entry**
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:337)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers(OpenSSLUtil.java:98)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)

As I am new to tomcat, not sure whats wrong with these steps. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TOMCAT SSL Error: Alias name does not identify a key entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799660/tomcat-ssl-error-alias-name-does-not-identify-a-key-entry)

Comment: There is no private key. We have only public key so this may not work.

Comment: If you are using mutual TLS you need: 1. a private key/certificate pair to authenticate the server to the client, 2. a CA certificate to verify the client's identity. Server authentication is required in TLS, so it will not work without a private key.

Comment: I checked with certificate provider and they said they cant share private key. Probably I will have see how to create the private key on my end then. I will check again. Thanks

Comment: I think I cannot add a private key to already generated cert and certificate provider cant provide the private key. What are the other options if any?

Comment: If you want to connect to Tomcat through TLS, you *need* a private key/certificate pair. For testing purposes it can be a self-signed certificate.